# Using mathematical induction to prove $a_n=3(-2)^n+2(3^n)-3(2^n)$ satisfies $a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}+3(2^n)$ for $n>1$

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I'm having trouble solving the following question

> Prove, using mathematical induction, that the relation
> $$a_n=3(-2)^n+2(3^n)-3(2^n)$$
> Satisfies the recursive function
> $$a_0=2,\quad a_1=-6,\quad a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}+3(2^n),\qquad \forall n>1$$

I first prove it for $n = 2$ which is true, then I assume that for $n = k$ my assumption is true but the problem is when I want to prove it for $n = k$, I used the assumption but still, I can't get there
Here's my solution:

**Step 1)** for $n=2$

$$a_2=3(-2)^2+2(3^2)-3(2^3)=18,\; a_2=-6+6(2)+3(2^2)=18$$

**Step 2)** For $n=k$ assume that
$$a_{k}=3(-2)^{k}+2(3^{k})-3(2^{k})=a_{k}=a_{k-1}+6a_{k-2}+3(2^{k})$$

**Step 3)** prove that for $n=k+1$,
$$a_{k+1}=3(-2)^{k+1}+2(3^{k+1})-3(2^{k+1})=a_{k+1}=a_k+6a_{k-1}+3(2^{k+1})$$

$a_{k+1}=a_k+6a_{k-1}+3(2^{k+1})$ replace $a_k$ from the assumption with $3(-2)^k+2(3^k)-3(2^k)$
$$a_{k+1}=3(-2)^k+2(3^k)+6a_{k-1}+3(2^{k+1}).$$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. It seems you need to use several base cases and [complete (strong) induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use strong induction instead, so assume that there exists a natural number $k$ such that the statement about $a_n$ is true for all integers up to $k$. After that, you can easily substitute $a_k$ and $a_{k-1}$ into the recurrence relation and show that the resulting expression equals $a_{k+1}$.